# Implementing a variable button with PHP and AJAX?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, variables, event-handling

I want to set up an image button (OPEN) with an `onclick()` function that renders a message including specific value changes in php.
The desired behaviour when user clicks on that button, is that it will be replaced with another image button (CLOSE).

Is it possible to set a variable button ? 
I have attempted to use variable link as follows:

**JavaScript:**

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
 else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
   var response=xmlhttp.responseText;
   x=response;
   if(x == 1)
   link="OPEN";
   else 
   link="CLOSE";

   var content = "<table style=\"padding-left:10px ;  float:right ; text-align:right\" > <tr><td style=\"float:right;color: blue;text-decoration: underline\" onmouseover=\"this.style.cursor='hand'\" onclick=\"function()\">"+link+"</td></tr></table>";
```

But, when user click on the 'OPEN' link and closes the page, next time he will get the CLOSE link instead of OPEN

Any suggestions on how to implement this correctly?

Comment: Will the button change dynamically while the page is open, or should there be different buttons on different openings?

Comment: you can change the __src__ attribute of an image whenever you want, and yes you can do it with a variable (as link) provided the image code is inside __content__

Comment: @David Mårtensson it should be different buttons on different openings (and I'm wondering it there a way to change the button dynamically while the page is open?)

Comment: @neu-rah if i add the image code inside content, it won't change. how will i change the src inside image code ?

Comment: if it works for your link it will work for the image, see example bellow

Comment: Yes, you can through DOM methods or jquery change the open page almost how much you like. The time when pages was immutable is long gone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this

```
if(x == 1) {
  link="OPEN";
  src="open.png"
} else {
  link="CLOSE";
  src="close.png"
}

var content = "<table style=\"padding-left:10px ;  float:right ; text-align:right\" > <tr><td style=\"float:right;color: blue;text-decoration: underline\" onmouseover=\"this.style.cursor='hand'\" onclick=\"function()\"><img src=\""+src+"\"/>"+link+"</td></tr></table>";
```

or use with an image somewhere

```
document.getElementById("imageid").src=src
```

Comment: Thank you. i see the it will be link + image. is there an way to use image button like http://www.irt.org/articles/js185/ ?

Comment: well you are using an onclick event on the table td, that wont play well with a button inside (or at least it will be confusing), but you can use a button image like:<INPUT TYPE="image" SRC=\""+src+"\"> and eventually move that onclick event to the button to have a more clear code because i'm not sure if all browsers will consider the button click vs the TD click all in the same way.